# Array not printing to second row of my second worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'll just provide snippets. Basically I have two sets of data on a master roster, and they're divided by an `X` value in column H of the roster. I want `X's` to be printed to Sheet1 of `Wb` and `Blanks` to be printed to Sheet2.

I have it working, but since it declares `FinalDest` as a singular variable, it doesn't start on row 2 of the Sheet2.

Example: if X's fill to row 10 of Sheet1, it will start Sheet2's data on row 11 instead of 2 (after headers).

```
 Sub Main()
  Dim Wb As Workbook
  Dim Data, Last, Login, SaveTyping
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
  Dim Dest1 As Range, Dest2 As Range, FinalDest As Range
  Set Wb = Workbooks("Template.xlsx")

  Set Dest1 = Wb.Sheets("Currently Eligible").Range("A2")
  Set Dest2 = Wb.Sheets("Newly Eligible").Range("A2")

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Roster")
    Data = .Range("AA2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  End With
```

After I declare my array, this is how I separate what's printed to the template.

```
   SaveTyping = Data(i, 8) 'Column my X's and Blanks are
    If InStr(SaveTyping, "X") Then
         Set FinalDest = Dest1
    End If
    If SaveTyping = "" Then
         Set FinalDest = Dest2
    End If

    For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)

      FinalDest.Offset(j, a) = Data(i, k) 'Where I need to tell array to print
      a = a + 1
    Next

    j = j + 1

  Next
```

`FinalDest` range picks up on the next row after where it left off from Sheet1, how do I prevent that and have it start on Row 2 for both sheets?

```
    Option Explicit

Sub Main()
  Dim Wb As Workbook 'Workbook I'm printing each managers employee roster to and saving off a copy to a folder
  Dim Data, Last, Login, chkVal 'Data = data I'm printing into template / Last = Manager name / Login = Manager Login ID
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long 'i = Data(row) / k = Data(column) / a = Wb(row) / j = Wb(column)
  Dim Dest1 As Range, Dest2 As Range, FinalDest As Range 'Dest1 = Sheets(1) of Wb / Dest2 = Sheets(2) of Wb

Set Wb = Workbooks("Template.xlsx") 'Sets template for each file cut

Set Dest1 = Wb.Sheets("Currently Eligible").Range("B2")
Set Dest2 = Wb.Sheets("Newly Eligible").Range("B2")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Data = .Range("AA2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Raw data
End With

Wb.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To UBound(Data) 'Row 1 to Ubound of Data(rows)

If Data(i, 1) <> Last Then 'only print array to Wb one manager at a time, we see when managers change because values in Data(i,1) will <> the next cell

  If i > 1 Then 'skip header

    Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
      ValidFileName(Login & " - " & Last & " - Shift Differential Validation.xlsx")

  End If

 With Sheets("Exempt Population")
 .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents 'Clears previous managers data
 End With

  Last = Data(i, 1) 'Manager last name is in Column A
  chkVal = Data(i, 8) 'Check for X or Blank in Column H
  Login = Data(i, 27) 'Manager login ID is in column AA

  j = 0 'Wb Column = 0

End If

a = 0 'Wb Row = 0

SaveTyping = Data(i, 8) 'Column my X's and Blanks are
    If InStr(SaveTyping, "X") Then
         Set FinalDest = Dest1
    End If
    If SaveTyping = "" Then
         Set FinalDest = Dest2
    End If



  For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2) 'Column 1 to Ubound of Data(columns)
  FinalDest.Offset(j, a) = Data(i, k)
  a = a + 1 'next Wb row
Next

j = j + 1 'next Wb column
Next

 SaveCopy Wb, Login, Last '<< save the last report


End Sub
```

Comment: you seem to be missing the opening For statement, and what is j

Comment: The for statement is just 'for i = 1 to uBound(Data)' and j is the destination column

Comment: in FinalDest.Offset(j, a), j seems to be a row, and a the column

Comment: Never mind, you’re right

Comment: ok, could you update your post to include beginning For etc, anything relevant so we can get an idea of what happens

Comment: @KaiAeberli I just updated below my post with all code at once. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @nicklanta You've still got your `j` and `a` mixed up - isn't `j` your destination column??

Comment: yea i think so too: they should be swapped. Its generally a good idea to name things row_wb rather than i or j, as i, j has no inherent meaning except that its some kind of index.

Comment: Ok, so regardless, how can I make sure each Set of data prints on row 2 of each worksheet? I did comment what each letter stands for in the code. If you look at the Dim __ as long section, you’ll see it laid out.

Comment: @dwirony I did define those variables at the top. Are you able to help with making sure the FinalDest prints to row two of each template worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the code a bit, giving proper names to indexes.

In terms of a solution to your issue, I added two different row indices, one for X one for blank. Depending on whether its an X or blank, you increment either the one or the other.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()


Dim Wb As Workbook 'Workbook I'm printing each managers employee roster to and saving off a copy to a folder
Dim Data, Last, Login, chkVal 'Data = data I'm printing into template / Last = Manager name / Login = Manager Login ID
Dim row_data As Long, col_wb As Long, col_data As Long, row_wb As Long
Dim Dest1 As Range, Dest2 As Range, FinalDest As Range 'Dest1 = Sheets(1) of Wb / Dest2 = Sheets(2) of Wb
Dim row_index_x As Long, row_index_blank As Long, isX As Long

Set Wb = Workbooks("Template.xlsx") 'Sets template for each file cut

Set Dest1 = Wb.Sheets("Currently Eligible").Range("B2")
Set Dest2 = Wb.Sheets("Newly Eligible").Range("B2")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Data = .Range("AA2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Raw data
End With

Wb.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' initialise row indices to 0, ignore header as Dest1 and Dest2 already at B2.
row_index_x = 0
row_index_blank = 0

For row_data = 1 To UBound(Data) 'Row 1 to Ubound of Data(rows)

    ' if manager name changed between this row and previous row
    If Data(row_data, 1) <> Last Then 'only print array to Wb one manager at a time, we see when managers change because values in Data(row_data,1) will <> the next cell

        If row_data > 1 Then 'skip header

            ' save wb every time manager changes
            Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
              ValidFileName(Login & " - " & Last & " - Shift Differential Validation.xlsx")

        End If

        With Sheets("Exempt Population")
            .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents 'Clears previous managers data
        End With

        Last = Data(row_data, 1) 'Manager last name is in Column A
        chkVal = Data(row_data, 8) 'Check for X or Blank in Column H
        Login = Data(row_data, 27) 'Manager login ID is in column AA

        ' reset output row every time manager name changes
        row_wb = 0 'Wb Row = 0

    End If

    ' for every data row, reset output column to zero (start a new row)
    col_wb = 0 'Wb Col = 0

    SaveTyping = Data(row_data, 8) 'Column my X's and Blanks are

    ' decide output destination
    If InStr(SaveTyping, "X") Then
         Set FinalDest = Dest1
         row_wb = row_index_x
         isX = 1 ' remember whether its X or blank
    End If

    If SaveTyping = "" Then
         Set FinalDest = Dest2
         row_wb = row_index_blank
         isX = 0
    End If


    ' Loop through all columns for one row of data
    ' keep output row the same, increase the output column
    For col_data = 1 To UBound(Data, 2) 'Column 1 to Ubound of Data(columns)
        FinalDest.Offset(row_wb, col_wb) = Data(row_data, col_data)
        col_wb = col_wb + 1 'next Wb column
    Next

    'row_wb = row_wb + 1 'next Wb row

    ' decide which row index to increase
    If isX = 1 Then
        row_index_x = row_index_x + 1
    Else
        row_index_blank = row_index_blank + 1
    End If

Next

SaveCopy Wb, Login, Last '<< save the last report

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I’ll be sure to test this first thing in the morning and let you know if I have any questions. Cheers!

Comment: I'm getting a compile error on the last Next statement, up above the `SaveCopy Wb, Login, Last`. That part is part of a private function I have, which I did not share, but where is the extra `For` statement that the debugger says I'm missing?

Comment: It's being caused by the last `IF` block statement. as in: `If isX = 1 Then` etc.. I take it out and it doesn't error out immediately. What could be causing that?

Comment: think so , changed it from "End" to "End If". My VBA syntax is a bit rusty, haven't used it in years ;)

Comment: So it went through, but after it cycles through the X's, it's placing the blanks right under them. I'm hoping to get the blanks to go to `Dest2`, which is in the second worksheet "Newly Eligible". Currently the `X's` go to Sheet1, but I need the blanks to move to the second sheet. How can that be done?

Comment: strange: If i understand well, FinalDest is set to either Dest1 or Dest2, depending on whether SaveTyping has an X in it or is blank. Can you check the logic there, if indeed it is setting FinalDest correctly?

Comment: yeah, `row_wb = row_index_x` `isX = 1` is what is causing it to shift to just the first sheet, I think. Before this was added, it was transferring to separate sheets properly.

This is in reference to the `If InStr` block statements at the bottom of the script

Comment: nope: so `row_wb = row_index_x` just takes the row counter for the X's and uses that in FinalDest to write the result in the correct row. `isX = 1` ensures that the right counter is incremented afterwards. Agree?

Comment: Agreed, unsure what's going on..

Here's how you could quickly test it out to see what's going on. 

1. create a .xlsm workbook with this code, and create a dummy data header, and then two dummy data rows (make sure column H in row 1 has an X and row 2 has a blank). You can fill in just random data for the other columns up until AA. 

2. Create a separate excel workbook labeled `Template.xlsx`.

3. In that workbook, label first worksheet `Currently Eligible` and second `Newly Eligible`. Make sure both sheets have headers

4. should be able to run through code and debug

Comment: I'd upload all of this for you, but my work has all of those cloud sites blocked

Comment: and make sure to put in `With Sheets(1)
            .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents 'Clears previous managers data
        End With` and `With Sheets(2)
            .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents 'Clears previous managers data
        End With`

Comment: I'm stepping through it, and  when it hits the first `If InStr(SaveTyping, "X") Then` statement, it should skip over it, but it doesn't. It cycles through, even though there isn't an X in the column, and skips over the second block IF statement.

Comment: I see - what would you expect it to do if an X cannot be found in the string, but the string is also not "" ? I don't see this case covered in your original code either actually.

Comment: Well I did do a trim and find & replace to make sure it's either X or Blank, no spaces. So how could that happen?

Comment: good point, it shouldn't. Can you send me the value of SaveTyping during the iteration where it should skip but it doesn't?

Comment: SaveTyping is only updating when the Manager Name changes. Otherwise SaveTyping just continues to be whatever it was on row 1 for that manager. It's ignored on all other rows. 

`SaveTyping = Data(row_Data, 8)`, so how can this be fixed to make sure it only keeps each 1 managers population on the template at a time, I can't have other managers seeing other managers employee info.

Comment: Would you like me to upload a template and raw data file to allow you to play around with it in VBE?

Comment: yes that would help. Also from what i can see, SaveTyping does change, it updates for every row, not only when the manager name changes.

Comment: so it would be good if you stepped through, and let me know what its value is just before the skipping happens.

Comment: https://send.firefox.com/download/08bb901ad5/#dN49ysUopqMhqsfMzd8h-A here’s the template and dummy data, Put Xs anywhere in column H of the .xlsm file and all of this will make sense

Comment: you changed the code compared to what you posted. Now the assignment to SaveTyping happens inside the if statement, so your statement that it changes only when manager changes is correct. But how could i know that? If we are not working on the same code I won't be able to help you.

Comment: actually I changed things around and got it to finally work. Sorry, I must have shifted that variable around on accident. Solution is verified and I have it up and running. Thank you!